# Bootstrap Vue does not display the css when using cards

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Recently I have strarted using bootsrap vue. I wrote the following code:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div>
        <b-card-group>
          <b-card border-variant="dark" header="Dark" align="center">
            <b-card-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</b-card-text>
          </b-card>
        </b-card-group>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import { BCard, BCardText, BCardGroup, } from 'bootstrap-vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            'b-card': BCard,
            'b-card-text': BCardText,
            'b-card-group': BCardGroup,
        },

        // More code
    }
</script>
```

The example was taken from the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/card/):

[image]

But for some reason I don't get the css design (the borders and the colors):

[image]

It's just shows plain text. What could be the issue? Am I not using the component right?

**EDIT**: My `main.js` looks like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from '../components/App.vue';
import router from '../router/router';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {
    'app': App
  },
});
```

But it still does not work.

**Edit2:** My webpack file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './public/js/main',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    stats: {
        warnings: false
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                // compiles js files
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }, {
                // compiles html files
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }, {
                // compile vue files
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            }, {
                // compile css files (basically, bootstrap)
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }, {
                // compile fonts and other type of files mentioned in regex
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: path.join('assets', 'fonts')
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js',
            'vue-router': 'vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js',
            'bootstrap-css': 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        },
    }
}
```

Could there be an issue?

Comment: Why do you have `import Vue from 'vue'` inside your component? Have you tried removing that line?

Comment: It stayed there from before. I removed it but it still does not work. I suspect the webpack now. I'll update my post.

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM to see if the classes are applied to your elements correctly?

Comment: @Hiws I tried to check the code in the devtools. The classes are exists but they are empty.

Comment: @vesii So what was the issue, I am facing the same.

Answer (score 2):

try to use class on your html element like :

```
<b-card-group>
   <b-card class="cards">
      <b-card-text>Lorem ipsum</b-card-text>
   </b-card>
</b-card-group>
```

Comment: Didn't help my :/

Answer (score 1):

```
// app.js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

write this in app.js file

For more detailed explanation https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/

Comment: Hi Noah, thank you but it looks like it is not the problem (please see my edit).